# Is there any case when passing by const & is not optimal for strings?

Tags: c++, reference

Recently I mentioned to a relative new user, that he should pass string parameters as `const std::string &` instead of passing them by value and received a comment:

> passing by const ref is not necessarily better then passing by a const value. Especially if you frequently read from it in the function.

While searching I only found the rule of thumb that recommends to use & or const & for any type `X` where `sizeof(X) > sizeof(void *)`.

So what could be such a case, where passing a string by (const) value is better than passing it by `const &`, if there is any?

Comment: Even if "you frequently read from it in the function," I would imagine any (decent) optimizing compiler would make a local copy in that case, thus only needing to dereference once.

Comment: The rule of thumb is obsolete as it doesn't take move semantics into account. If you want to make a copy of the string inside your function (e.g. store it in some data structure), passing by const value is better.

Comment: @Adrian no, compilers cannot make a local copy for optimisation purposes.

Comment: @n.m. Wouldn't this create one copy in either case?

Comment: With a reference it may create more than one copy, passing by const value eliminates that (there's always just one copy. eeroika's answer covers this. `std::string_view` is probably better in most cases but it is only for strings. There is no such option for an object that is not a sequence of anything.

Comment: Passing by value (non-const) can sometimes be more efficient due to move semantics and rvalues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any case when passing by const & is not optimal for strings?

In cases where the caller doesn't have a `std::string` object in the first place, creating one in order to pass a reference is non optimal. `std::string_view` argument covers these cases, as well as most cases where string reference is optimal.

> what could be such a case, where passing a string by (const) value is better than passing it by const &, if there is any?

The text that you quote describes such case:

> > ... Especially if you frequently read from it in the function.

To explain *why*: Copying into an argument occurs only once per function call, while indirection through a reference (or string view) occurs on every access within the function. Given that neither is free, there must be some number of indirections that are more expensive than the copy.

Whether that number is ever reached in your program is another matter. The number is heavily influenced by the capabilities of the system, and length of the input string. If you measure that passing by value is statistically faster (with a reasonable p-value) in your program on your target system, then it may be worth it. But this is quite rare case, which is why the reference (or string view) is recommended default choice unless the function needs a copy.

Note that passing by **const** value is often not a good idea since it forces the function to copy the string again in cases where it could otherwise move it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why this is case. It seems that this is a highly situational optimization.